# CentOS 8 /bin/sh: line 1: a: No such file or directory

Tags: curl, sh, centos8

Got my CentOS 8 VPS, login as root and want to run the command `curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` but getting `/bin/sh: line 1: a: No such file or directory`

So I found `/bin/sh` located under the system directory "/", so tried `../bin/sh` for no avail.

Checked the file encoding and found it to be binary i.e. `head -1 ../bin/sh` is useless to check typo in line 1.

How can I run this command? Is it correct to run it from the root directory? I got the same error when run from `/home/<userName>`. Please see terminal image. Thanks

**Update:**
The correct command should be `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` and not `curl install.meteor.com | /bin/sh` which was copied from non meteor web site.

Comment: It's the thing downloaded from `install.meteor.com` that has a problem on its first line, not your shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what you actually get from the `curl` command:

```
$ curl install.meteor.com
<a href="https://install.meteor.com/">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

The `<a` is interpreted by the shell as an input redirection, but there is no file named `a` to read from.

As you noticed, you need to use the `https` URL to get the actual shell script to execute. Either `/bin/sh` or `sh` should work, as `sh` is *usually* installed in `/bin`.